# Incompatible types: bad return type in lambda expression while converting Integer stream to String stream?

Tags: java

I am working on a codewars problem, here is what my code looks like

```
    public static String longest (String s1, String s2) {
    // your code
   
  return (s1+s2)
    .chars()
    .distinct()
    .sorted()
    .map(i -> String.valueOf(i))
    .collect(Collectors.joining());

}

 I am getting the following error
 
 Main.java:24: error: incompatible types: bad return type in lambda
 expression
         .map(i -> String.valueOf(i))
                                 ^
     String cannot be converted to int
```

can someone explain to mo why I am getting the error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

[`String.chars`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#chars()) returns an `IntStream` and not a `Stream<Character>` or `Stream<Integer>`. The [`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#map(java.util.function.IntUnaryOperator)) method on `IntStream` requires an [`IntUnaryOperator`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/IntUnaryOperator.html), which is basically a function that takes an `int` and returns another `int`. Therefore, the compiler expected your lambda expression in the call to `map` to return an `int` instead of a `String`.

What you want is [`mapToObj`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#mapToObj(java.util.function.IntFunction)) which takes an `int` and turns it into an object of some kind (in this case, a `String`).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to return a string made of the distinct chars of the prameters passed, you could split the concatenated string at each char and collect all distinct back to string, i.e something like:

```
 public static String foo(String s1, String s2){
    return Pattern.compile("")
                  .splitAsStream(s1+s2)
                  .distinct()
                  .sorted()
                  .collect(Collectors.joining());
}
```

or if you want to stick to your first aproach, you can use StringBuilder or StringWriter to build a string with your distinct chars

```
public static String foo1(String s1, String s2){
    return  (s1+s2).chars()
                   .distinct()
                   .sorted()                       
                   .collect(StringBuilder::new, (sb, c) -> sb.append((char) c),StringBuilder::append)
                   .toString();
}
```

Comment: Your first option is brilliant!